# How to add subcollection to a subcollection in firestore, react app

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I create subcollection of budgets in collection of users like this:

```
const addBudget = async (budget: Budget, userId: string) => {
  await addDoc(collection(db, 'users', userId, 'budgets'), { name: budget.name, max: budget.max });
};
```

The id of the budget is auto generated, but then I want to add another subcollection in budgets:

```
const addExpense = async (expense: Expense, userId: string) => {
  await addDoc(collection(db, 'users', userId, 'budgets', expense.budgetId /* auto generated id should be here here*/, 'expenses'), {
    description: expense.description,
    expenseValue: expense.expenseValue
  });
};
```

This is my structure in firestore, but it doesnt work right now, it creates new budget id of 1 and then creates subcollection of expenses:
[image]

How can I add this subcollection of expenses other way?

Answer (score 0):

The [`addDoc` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#adddoc) returns a `DocumentReference`. So if you capture that, you can read its `id` and use that to create another subcollection under it.

```
const budgetRef = await addDoc(collection(db, 'users', userId, 'budgets'), { name: budget.name, max: budget.max });
const budgetId = budgetRef.id;
...
```